# Is this the best architecture/design to handle requests with large payload and heavy time-consuming process to handle each request in Java Ecosystem?

Tags: java, spring, rest, architecture, software-design

Which is the best architecture to handle multiple http requests sending a list of ids (with more than 1000 ids in each request) and each request will be a heavy time-consuming process that communicate with other systems (that uses SOAP or REST) and saves data into a RDBMS?

Should I send the ids in a POST HTTP request?

Should I use Spring Framework Async/Futures (without return) in a Resource/Controller REST to handle the Time-consuming process and return HTTP 202 Accepted (and maybe an ID to query the status of the process or the resource)?

Or Is it good if my Resources/Controllers REST only put the messages in a JMS Queue (maybe a persistent queue for each REST method) and Message-Driven Beans (for each method) consume the messages and process the request?

It is a good idea if my Resources/Controllers REST or a class acting like a proxy save the requests for my system and other systems responses in a database for logging purposes and to fix problems? Or should I use the retry feature in JMS for example?

Comment: This question is way too broad and cannot easily be answered. All of your usecases might be valid depending on your requirements, and all of them can be implemented right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with dunni; however, your general requirements sound like JMS would be a good place to start. That would allow clients to drop off requests and allow back end components to work on the requests as they are able. Of course, you need enough back end power to get all the requests completed in a reasonable time frame.